# Java Httpclient login with POST - two stage login?

Tags: java, forms, http, post, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to login to a website through form using *POST*. I can send the params, which are accepted but then I'm redirected to a page where there's other form which looks like this

Content eliminated for security reasons.

```
<form name="form" id="forwardParticipantForm" class="box2" method="post" action="https://faturas.portaldasfinancas.gov.pt/painelAdquirente.action">
        <input type="hidden" name="nif" value="......."/>
        <input type="hidden" name="userID" value="......."/>
        <input type="hidden" name="userName" value="......."/>
        <input type="hidden" name="sessionID" value="......."/>
        <input type="hidden" name="tc" value="........"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="tv" value="......."/>
        <input type="hidden" name="partID" value=".......">
        <input type="hidden" name="sign" value="......."/>
```

And the only thing written in this page is "Login successful. You're being redirected in a secure way to the requested service". The website then automatically redirects the user to the "main page".

But in my program the connection stands in this page and I can't finish my login and, consequently, i can't retrieve the information that I want.

It's not a problem with redirects as redirects are being followed. If I try to *GET* a page which requires login, I'm redirected to this page again but I receive a new *sessionID* and *sign*. I've also tried to make a *POST* to this page with the params that I receive but the same thing happens.

EDIT: Inspecting element in browser, there are two *POST*, the first with the credentials and after that, the second one with the params that I receive in the form above.

code:

```
BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().
            setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0").
            setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore).
            setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).
            build();


    try {
        //GET
        HttpGet httpGet1 = new HttpGet("https://www.acesso.gov.pt/jsp/loginRedirectForm.jsp?path=painelAdquirente.action&partID=EFPF");
        CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httpGet1);

        try {
            HttpEntity entity1 = response1.getEntity();
            System.out.println("Login form get: 1st get " + response1.getStatusLine());
            EntityUtils.consume(entity1);

        } finally {
            response1.close();
        }

        //POST - LOGIN
        HttpPost authPost = new HttpPost("https://www.acesso.gov.pt/jsp/loginRedirect.jsp");
        // Request parameters and other properties.
        List <NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "......."));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "......."));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("partID", "EFPF"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("path", "consultarDocumentosAdquirente.action?dataInicioFilter=2015-08-01"));
        authPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));


        System.out.println();
        CloseableHttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute(authPost);

        try {
            HttpEntity entity2 = response2.getEntity();
            System.out.println("Login form get: 2nd post " + response2.getStatusLine());
            EntityUtils.consume(entity2);
        } finally {
            response2.close();
        }
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
```

Comment: Add code you are using

Comment: code added to the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to login properly. The param partID, as it doesn't end like the others ( *">* instead of *"/>* ) was missing a letter because I was fetching it with line.length()-3.